# Количество n-буквенных слов в файле C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, файлы

Есть класс, метод в котором должен вывести количество слов, состоящих из n символов из открытого текстового файла.

```
 //Открывает файл
 private async void ButtonBrowse_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {            
        FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
        openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
        openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".txt");
        StorageFile file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
        if (file != null)
        {
            LabelPath.Text = file.Path;
            TextFile.Text = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);
        }
        else
        {
            //  
        }
    }

    private void ButtonCount_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       LabelNCount.Text = "Number of n-count words: " + CountClass.nCount(TextFile.Text, Int32.Parse(TextNCount.Text));
    }

    //Метод из класса CountClass, в котором должен происходить подсчёт
    public static int nCount(String file, int numberOfCharacters)
    {
        return file.Split('\n').Count(line => line.Length > numberOfCharacters); //это или не работает, или лыжи не едут
    }
```

Проблемы с подсчётом всех слов в файле нету. Но как посчитать слова определённой длины?

Comment: Метод `nCount` выводит количество строк в файле, но не количество слов. Только если у Вас в файле в одной строке ни одно слово. `\n` - переход на новую строку.

Comment: Кроме того, что написали выше, вы ищите количество строк с большим количеством символов, чем `numberOfCharacters` а не равенством.

Comment: @Ev_Hyper , да точно, недосмотрел.

Comment: Что тогда я могу использовать чтобы найти слова необходимой мне длины?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Найти количество слов необходимой длины как-то так:

```
public int GetCountWordsByLength(string text, int length)
{
    char[] delimiters = new char[] { ' ', '\r', '\n', ',', '?', '-' }; // разделители
    var words = text.Split(delimiters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); // все слова
    return words.Where(x => x.Length == length).ToList().Count; // количество слов по условию 
}
```

Ну и вызов метода:

```
string text = "я веселный молочник\n кто сказал, что я один?";
var count = GetCountWordsByLength(text, 3); // количество слов длинной в 3 символа
```

Comment: Спасибо. Только исправь на `return words.Where(x => x.Length == length).ToList().Count`

Comment: @AlexandrSmushko , тогда и тип возвращаемого значения на 'int' ) не за что, тут главное ход мысли ) 'Count' можно и к переменной потом добавить ) сейчас исправлю